# Java execute method SYNC/ASYNC based on priority

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, multiprocessing

I do not have much experience with priority-based executions in Java or Multithreading, so I am writing this question here to get your suggestions/ideas.

As per my requirement, I need to execute external API based on priority of `Product` property configured in my application.

Sample product structure #1:

```
ProductName ParentProductName ExternalAPIName Priority
Abc         parent            api1            1
Abc         parent            api2            2
Abc         parent            api3            1
```

Sample product structure #2:

```
ProductName ParentProductName ExternalAPIName Priority
Abc         parent            api1            1
Abc         parent            api2            1
Abc         parent            api3            1
```

Execution for structure #1:

Based on priority, invoke external API in sequence. Since there are different priorities, execute the underlying API's parallelly and let them complete asynchronously. SO here I am not waiting for 1 async method to complete its execution and then invoke other and so on.

Execution for structure #2:

Based on priority, since all have same priority, execute the underlying API in sequence and wait for the invocation to complete before invoking second API.

I am at my wits end thinking of an algorithm/code sample for this problem. Would really appreciate some pointers here.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I do not have an idea on this or the approach to be taken..